# socket.emit only emitting to emitter

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I am using react-native with socket.io to send and receive contact requests but my code is only emitting to the emitter and to no one else.

**This is the server side:**

```
users = []; // Each time a new user joins the server they are saved in this array
socket.on('create connection', function(data, callback) {
            if(data.receiverId in users) { // If the user you want to add is online then callback is true else callback is false
                // The underneath line is the one that I will be using but nothing happend
                //io.sockets.in(data.receiverId).emit('save room', data);
                // So I created this one to see if I actually was emitting something
                socket.emit('save room', data); // I found out that the emitting was working but only with the emitter
                callback(true);
            }else
                callback(false);
        });
```

So my conclusion is that my server side is correct and the problem lies on my client side

**This is my client side:**

```
constructor() {
        this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.15.4:8000');

        this.socket.on('save room', function (data) { // This is where the server calls the emit. It was at first inside the connect function but I moved it to the constructor to see if that way all clients could get it, results are the same
            Alert.alert(
                'Accept Connection?',
                'User: '+data.emitterId+' sent you a connection request',
                [
                    {
                        text: 'Accept',
                        onPress: () => {},
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Refuse',
                        onPress: () => {},
                    },
                ],
                {cancellable: false}
            );
        })
    }

@action connect(data, callback1) { // this access the function we had previously in the server
        this.socket.emit('create connection', data, function (callback2) {
            if(!callback2)
                Alert.alert(
                    'User Offline',
                    'This user is currently offline try again later',
                    [
                        {
                            text: 'OK',
                            onPress: () => {callback1(false)},
                        },
                    ],
                    {cancellable: false}
                );
            else {
                callback1(true)
            }
        });
    }
```

I think the problem lies on where I place the ***this.socket.on('save room')*** function, but in react-native I really do not know where to put it.

Comment: Could you try and share results of the following;

1) Move ```this.socket.on``` into ```componentDidMount();```

2) Instead of ```socket.emit```, try ```socket.broadcast.emit```

Comment: If I do number one not even the emitter receives the alert but with number two it works! But if I use it like that all users online will receive the alert. How can I do it like this "io.sockets.in(data.receiverId).emit('save room', data);"?

Comment: ```socket.broadcast.emit``` emits your message to everyone except the sender. So the problem should be with you not being recognized as sender. Could you try to add ```this.socket.open()``` in constructor before ```this.socket.on```?

Comment: yes, sorry it emits the message to everyone except the sender

Comment: I found out that I could do this: socket.broadcast.to(data.receiverId).emit('save room', data); and it gives me the expected result. But why socket.emit would not work on both ends?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@H. Tugkan kibar** and **@azium** I realized that the problem was on my server side the correct way to emit to a specific user is like this:

```
socket.broadcast.to().emit();
```